# Git Extensions stopped working after forced restart

Tags: windows-8.1, git-extensions

Git extensions stopped working on my computer after I performed a forced restart. I need help getting it back on line.

My computer runs on windows 8.1. Leading up to the error, my computer ran out of memory (RAM) and froze. after about 5 minutes of no response, I powered down the machine by holding down the power button. I then started my machine up again and Git-Extensions would no longer launch. clicking on the git-extensions Icon would prompt no error. Rather, the computer would acknowledge that I had clicked on something, but fail to launch the program. The same result came from navigating into the file where the executable is located and clicking on it directly.

My efforts to fix the problem are as follows. I restarted my machine. Git extensions still didn't launch. I went to the download site for Git-extensions and selected to have my local installation repaired. Afterwards, Git extensions still would not launch. I uninstalled and re-installed Git-Extensions. Still, Git extensions is not launching.

Any Ideas as to why Git-Extensions would suddenly stop working and how to fix the problem? Thanks.

Comment: More information on the error: Faulting application name: GitExtensions.exe, version: 2.47.3.0, time stamp: 0x528680a0
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.3.9600.17055, time stamp: 0x532954fb
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x0000000000005bf8
Faulting process id: 0xf30
Faulting application start time: 0x01cf7c76e2a1f1da
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\GitExtensions\GitExtensions.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 206f0ec3-e86a-11e3-8274-008cfa96e138
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID

Answer (score 0):

Downgraded to Git-extensions 2.4.

https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/2185